# Higher dimension adjacency

Tags: graph, geometry, computational-geometry, adjacency-list, convex-hull

Given a convex hull of a set of points in an arbitrary dimension (**D**) space and given the separate point outside from an interior of the convex hull. There is a set of *visible* (from the separate point) facets (assume, that all the facets and other geometric objects (faces) is simplexes, id est simplicial faces). There is a set of *invisible* facets. There is a subset of *visible* facets, each of which is adjacent to one or more of *invisible* facets. Let's call they *before-the-horizon facets* and its invisible counterparts - *over-the-horizon* facets. The geometric object common for both adjacent facets (**(D - 1)**-dimensional faces) calling the *ridge* and its dimensionality is **(D - 2)**. All the ridges forms a continious and closed chain. So, there is some another kind of adjacency (applicable only for before-the-horizon facets): each two adjacent ridges have two corresponding visible facets, which, in turn, can be or can be not adjacent in common sense, but adjacent in derivative sense (they are *weak* adjacent via the adjacency of its horizon ridges). The common object for two adjacent ridges (**(D - 2)**-faces) is so-called *peak* (**(D - 3)**-face).

We want to complete the convex hull by adding the separate point. We can start from the first known visible facet and recursively check for visibility all the its neighbours and so on in order to produce a graph of visible facets or some other reasonable data structure (for the first case in the further list is simply a two lists (not somehow ordered): over-the-horizon facets and before-the-horizon facets).

We have the next problem: we should to construct a new facets instead of visible facets (which later will be deleted) and provide an adjacency relation between all of the newly constructed facets.

There are at least two approaches:

- For each over-the-horizon facet to construct the new facet by means of copying its horizon ridge (**(D - 1)** vertices) and the separate point. Initialize the set of its neighbours with corresponding over-the-horizon facet. After a completion of the constructing of the incomplete new facets we should supplement its neighbours lists with additional **(D - 1)** other facets strictly from the set of newly created facets. It can be done by means of **complete enumeration** of all possible pairs from the last mentioned set and check whether the both of constituents have **(D - 1)** common points and each its own unique point which is not present in list of vertices of its counterpart. About ~**N<sup>2</sup> * D** equality comparizon operations required on the average to detect all the adjacent pairs.
- We can **keep track of the adjacency structure** for facets on each step. I mean the next approach: either breadth-first traverse of facets, or depth-first traversal (I can't infer which one (it is by the way the main problem of the my doubts)) started from first known visible facet gives us the set of before-the-horizon facets and its over-the-horizon neighbours. If we will be careful, than we will obtain the tree, which completely (except of its invisible leafs) composed of **D**-degree nodes (which are representing facets). Each its node contain a list of its neighbours (i.e. each facet data structure contain a list of its adjacent facets). The degree is the number of neighbours.

I interested in development of the second approach. My problem is understanding of *weak* adjacency relation (in the sense described above) between before-the-horizon facets and how to keep track of it during the traverse: how to find (or how to know on the final step) all the "neighbouring" before-the-horizon facets for given before-the-horizon facet?

[There is](https://bitbucket.org/tomilov/quickhull/) my hand-written **C++** code of Quickhull algorithm implementation; I'll be happy if it will ever come handy.

Comment: Each facet contain **(D - 1)** ridges. Each ridge contain **(D - 2)** peaks. So there is about **N * (D - 1) * (D - 2)** memory to keep track the adjacency.